# Order by in Oracle Pivot Statement not working

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

In oracle, I'm using this pivot statement to get all Clauses attached with every PO_ITEM_ID.

```
select * from(
SELECT po_item_id, case when  note_nbr LIKE '%C505%' then 'C505'
when  note_nbr LIKE '%C506%' then 'C506'
when  note_nbr LIKE '%C507%' then 'C507'
when  note_nbr LIKE '%C508%' then 'C508'
when  note_nbr LIKE '%C003%' then 'C003' end c
FROM SMP_PO_ITEM_NOTES
WHERE
(note_nbr LIKE '%C505%' or note_nbr LIKE '%C506%' or note_nbr LIKE '%C507%' or note_nbr LIKE '%C508%'or note_nbr LIKE '%C003%'))
pivot(
count(po_item_id) for c in ('C505','C506','C507','C508','C003')
)
ORDER BY po_item_id DESC
```

The code executes fine without the Order by statement. When order by statement is added it throws an exception as invalid identifier PO_ITEM_ID.

I need my output to look like this. Appreciate any kind help

| PO_ITEM_ID | C505 | C506 | C507 | C508 | C003 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0002 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0003 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: If you remove `order by` you'll see that `PO_ITEM_ID` is not returned by the query because it's used as a value for aggregation in `pivot`. Just add another column for aggregation in the subquery. For example, `...PO_ITEM_ID as measure ... pivot(count(measure) for ... )`

Answer (score 0):

Your code aggregates (Count) column PO_ITEM_ID, so  that column does not exist as a column at all - counted values are placed as values in appropriate columns C505, C506, .. .. C003. That is why Order By clause throws an error.
One of the options is to do the count before pivoting to get you the expected result. Try it llike below:

```sql
Select  PO_ITEM_ID, Nvl(C505, 0) "C505",  Nvl(C506, 0) "C506", Nvl(C507, 0) "C507", Nvl(C508, 0) "C508", Nvl(C003, 0) "C003"
From    ( Select    PO_ITEM_ID, CASE  WHEN  NOTE_NBR LIKE '%C505%' THEN 'C505'
                                      WHEN  NOTE_NBR LIKE '%C506%' THEN 'C506'
                                      WHEN  NOTE_NBR LIKE '%C507%' THEN 'C507'
                                      WHEN  NOTE_NBR LIKE '%C508%' THEN 'C508'
                                      WHEN  NOTE_NBR LIKE '%C003%' THEN 'C003' END "C",
                    Count(*) "CNT"
          From  tbl
          Group By  PO_ITEM_ID, CASE  WHEN  NOTE_NBR LIKE '%C505%' THEN 'C505'
                                      WHEN  NOTE_NBR LIKE '%C506%' THEN 'C506'
                                      WHEN  NOTE_NBR LIKE '%C507%' THEN 'C507'
                                      WHEN  NOTE_NBR LIKE '%C508%' THEN 'C508'
                                      WHEN  NOTE_NBR LIKE '%C003%' THEN 'C003' END  )
        PIVOT(  MAX(CNT) FOR C in ('C505' "C505", 'C506' "C506",'C507' "C507",'C508' "C508",'C003' "C003")  )
ORDER BY PO_ITEM_ID
```

With this sample data

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (   Select '001' "PO_ITEM_ID",  'C505' "NOTE_NBR" From Dual Union All
            Select '002',               'C506' From Dual Union All
            Select '003',               'C506' From Dual Union All
            Select '003',               'C506' From Dual Union All
            Select '003',               'C505' From Dual Union All
            Select '001',               'C508' From Dual Union All
            Select '002',               'C508' From Dual Union All
            Select '002',               'C506' From Dual Union All
            Select '001',               'C508' From Dual Union All
            Select '002',               'C003' From Dual    
        )
```

... the result should be like

```sql
PO_ITEM_ID       C505       C506       C507       C508       C003
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
001                 1          0          0          2          0 
002                 0          2          0          1          1 
003                 1          2          0          0          0
```